# Odd behavior with list bullets in Internet Explorer 10-11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Check this out, the bullets are on the picture:

[image]

Picture css:

```
    img[src="img/tecnicos.jpg"] {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

Bullet list css:

```
    #contenido ul {
    max-width: 75ch;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Work Sans';
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    list-style: disc;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <h2>BLa</h2>
        <img src="img/image.jpg" alt=''>
        <ul>
            <li>Line 1</li>
            <li>Line 2</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
```

Li element has no css.

On Chrome and Firefox the bullets are displayed right where it should, next to the text.

Tips?

Comment: Need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to the list fixes it if you don't need the list to flow around the image: https://jsfiddle.net/jameson5555/95koe4sg/2/

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If it does need to wrap, you could add something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jameson5555/95koe4sg/3/

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new block formatting context with

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```